# How a function passes its arguments to its inner function call (not nested new functions) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope, arguments

I am learning the javascript scope chains. When a variable is declared in a function, it can't been seen in another function. For example, myVar is declared in function a and can't been seen in function b:

```
function b() {
  console.log(myVar);
}

function a() {
  var myVar = 2;
  b();
}

a(); //->myVar is not defined
```

But why a function can pass its argument to its inner function call (not nested new functions)? Are arguments supposed to be the function's local variables?

```
function b(str) {
  console.log(str);
}

function a(str) {
  b(str);
}

a("a's argument"); //->"a's argument"
```

Comment: Everything in JS is passed by value, even objects and arrays are passed by value, why these values couldn't be passed to which ever function coder wants to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but as you pass the `str` prop explicitly to the b function, it's valid.

What should not work :

```
function b() {
  console.log(str);
}

function a(str) {
  b();
}

a("a's argument"); //->undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the two variables in your example have the same name means nothing, as they're defined in different scopes.

When in function `a` you do

```
b(str);
```

What you're doing is coping the value of parameter `str` in function `a` to another variable, the parameter `str` in function `b`.
Internally, variables are just simple ways to referencing memory addresses. When you call `b(str)` you're copying into `b->str` the same value `a->str` holds, but, in the end, you have two different memory addresses containing the same value (the pointer of the `a's argument` string).

The JavaScript interpreter/compiler knows that they are two different addresses, as they belong to two different scopes.

If you do:

```js
function b(str) {
   setTimeout(function() { console.log(str) }, 1000);
}

function a(str) {
   b(str);
   str = 'new value';
   console.log(str);
}

a("a's argument");
```

You'll see that, despite changing `b->str`'s value in `a`, when the `setTimeout` in `b` executes, it logs out the original value, even though it is logged after the `console.log` in `a` which shows the changed value.